# Не могу получить ответ от OpenWeatherMap

Tags: android, сеть, okhttp

Я хочу получить ответ от OpenWeatherMap.
Вот код:

```
private void getWeatherData() {
    final String urlForCurrent = makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() ;
    final Request curRequest = new Request.Builder().url(urlForCurrent).build() ;
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MA - Метод getWeatherData() - создал реквест");

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MA - Метод makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() = 1" );
            return okHttpClient.newCall(curRequest).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }).thenApply(response -> {
        if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
            try {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MA - Метод makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() = 2" );
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }).thenApply(response -> {
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MA - Метод makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() = 3" );
                return new WeatherParser(response).parseData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }).thenAcceptAsync(weather -> {
        if (weather != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MA - Метод makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() = 4" );
            weatherDescription.setText(weather.getDescription());
            temperature.setText(weather.getTemperature() + "");
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(MainActivity.this));
}
```

Вот логи:

2020-07-04 10:45:26.010 9858-9858/? D/myLogs: MA - Метод getSettings() degreesType = Celsius , City = London
2020-07-04 10:45:26.012 9858-9858/? D/myLogs: MA - Метод makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() = http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=****
2020-07-04 10:45:26.020 9858-9858/? D/myLogs: MA - Метод getWeatherData() - создал реквест
2020-07-04 10:45:26.022 9858-9914/? D/myLogs: MA - Метод makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall() = 1

Строку, полученную в методе makeTextOfCurrentWeatherCall(), я могу открыть в браузере. Значит дело не в ней.
Разрешение на Интернет в манифесте я добавил.
По логам я не получаю ответ.
Что я не делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ:

надо было прописать строку android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" в манифесте.

```
    *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest ...>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            ...
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            ...>
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>*
```

Comment: Лучше смените схему на https.